# I'm learning how to connect sqlite to spark from the book Spark the Definitive Guide

Tags: sqlite, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Jupyter Notebook.

Below is the mentioned code used to connect `pyspark` to sqlite:

```py
driver = "org.sqlite.JDBC"

path = "/data/flight-data/jdbc/my-sqlite.db"

url = "jdbc:sqlite:" + path

tablename = "flight_info"

dbDataFrame = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", url)\
.option("dbtable", tablename).option("driver", driver).load()
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o121.load.  
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
```

Please help me resolve the error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

Spark using the JDBC API is unable to find the class 'org.sqlite.JDBC' because it is not in the classpath for spark.

### Solution

You may download the jar file from --> [Maven Online Repository](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.28.0/sqlite-jdbc-3.28.0.jar) and place it in the `jars` folder. Restart your notebook/application

### Reference/Resources

SQLITE JDBC download link from maven - https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.28.0/sqlite-jdbc-3.28.0.jar

Comment: Great! Please mark this as the accepted answer so that others searching on stackoverflow with a similar issue may also find it useful.